# ERRNO errors and explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, errno

I noticed that often you get ERRNO errors, but have no clue what they mean. Here is some guide, that is helping me and might help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In console

```
110.times do |errno| #there are not more then 110 ERRNO errors
   puts "#{ errno } => #{ SystemCallError.new(errno).inspect }"
end
```

Results. Enjoy your debuging and code digging

```
0 => #<Errno::NOERROR: Undefined error: 0>
1 => #<Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted>
2 => #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory>
3 => #<Errno::ESRCH: No such process>
4 => #<Errno::EINTR: Interrupted system call>
5 => #<Errno::EIO: Input/output error>
6 => #<Errno::ENXIO: Device not configured>
7 => #<Errno::E2BIG: Argument list too long>
8 => #<Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error>
9 => #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
10 => #<Errno::ECHILD: No child processes>
11 => #<Errno::EDEADLK: Resource deadlock avoided>
12 => #<Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory>
13 => #<Errno::EACCES: Permission denied>
14 => #<Errno::EFAULT: Bad address>
15 => #<Errno::ENOTBLK: Block device required>
16 => #<Errno::EBUSY: Resource busy>
17 => #<Errno::EEXIST: File exists>
18 => #<Errno::EXDEV: Cross-device link>
19 => #<Errno::ENODEV: Operation not supported by device>
20 => #<Errno::ENOTDIR: Not a directory>
21 => #<Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory>
22 => #<Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument>
23 => #<Errno::ENFILE: Too many open files in system>
24 => #<Errno::EMFILE: Too many open files>
25 => #<Errno::ENOTTY: Inappropriate ioctl for device>
26 => #<Errno::ETXTBSY: Text file busy>
27 => #<Errno::EFBIG: File too large>
28 => #<Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device>
29 => #<Errno::ESPIPE: Illegal seek>
30 => #<Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system>
31 => #<Errno::EMLINK: Too many links>
32 => #<Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe>
33 => #<Errno::EDOM: Numerical argument out of domain>
34 => #<Errno::ERANGE: Result too large>
35 => #<Errno::EAGAIN: Resource temporarily unavailable>
36 => #<Errno::EINPROGRESS: Operation now in progress>
37 => #<Errno::EALREADY: Operation already in progress>
38 => #<Errno::ENOTSOCK: Socket operation on non-socket>
39 => #<Errno::EDESTADDRREQ: Destination address required>
40 => #<Errno::EMSGSIZE: Message too long>
41 => #<Errno::EPROTOTYPE: Protocol wrong type for socket>
42 => #<Errno::ENOPROTOOPT: Protocol not available>
43 => #<Errno::EPROTONOSUPPORT: Protocol not supported>
44 => #<Errno::ESOCKTNOSUPPORT: Socket type not supported>
45 => #<Errno::ENOTSUP: Operation not supported>
46 => #<Errno::EPFNOSUPPORT: Protocol family not supported>
47 => #<Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT: Address family not supported by protocol family>
48 => #<Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use>
49 => #<Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Can't assign requested address>
50 => #<Errno::ENETDOWN: Network is down>
51 => #<Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable>
52 => #<Errno::ENETRESET: Network dropped connection on reset>
53 => #<Errno::ECONNABORTED: Software caused connection abort>
54 => #<Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer>
55 => #<Errno::ENOBUFS: No buffer space available>
56 => #<Errno::EISCONN: Socket is already connected>
57 => #<Errno::ENOTCONN: Socket is not connected>
58 => #<Errno::ESHUTDOWN: Can't send after socket shutdown>
59 => #<Errno::ETOOMANYREFS: Too many references: can't splice>
60 => #<Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out>
61 => #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused>
62 => #<Errno::ELOOP: Too many levels of symbolic links>
63 => #<Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long>
64 => #<Errno::EHOSTDOWN: Host is down>
65 => #<Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host>
66 => #<Errno::ENOTEMPTY: Directory not empty>
67 => #<Errno::EPROCLIM: Too many processes>
68 => #<Errno::EUSERS: Too many users>
69 => #<Errno::EDQUOT: Disc quota exceeded>
70 => #<Errno::ESTALE: Stale NFS file handle>
71 => #<Errno::EREMOTE: Too many levels of remote in path>
72 => #<Errno::EBADRPC: RPC struct is bad>
73 => #<Errno::ERPCMISMATCH: RPC version wrong>
74 => #<Errno::EPROGUNAVAIL: RPC prog. not avail>
75 => #<Errno::EPROGMISMATCH: Program version wrong>
76 => #<Errno::EPROCUNAVAIL: Bad procedure for program>
77 => #<Errno::ENOLCK: No locks available>
78 => #<Errno::ENOSYS: Function not implemented>
79 => #<Errno::EFTYPE: Inappropriate file type or format>
80 => #<Errno::EAUTH: Authentication error>
81 => #<Errno::ENEEDAUTH: Need authenticator>
82 => #<SystemCallError: Device power is off>
83 => #<SystemCallError: Device error>
84 => #<Errno::EOVERFLOW: Value too large to be stored in data type>
85 => #<SystemCallError: Bad executable (or shared library)>
86 => #<SystemCallError: Bad CPU type in executable>
87 => #<SystemCallError: Shared library version mismatch>
88 => #<SystemCallError: Malformed Mach-o file>
89 => #<Errno::ECANCELED: Operation canceled>
90 => #<Errno::EIDRM: Identifier removed>
91 => #<Errno::ENOMSG: No message of desired type>
92 => #<Errno::EILSEQ: Illegal byte sequence>
93 => #<Errno::ENOATTR: Attribute not found>
94 => #<Errno::EBADMSG: Bad message>
95 => #<Errno::EMULTIHOP: EMULTIHOP (Reserved)>
96 => #<Errno::ENODATA: No message available on STREAM>
97 => #<Errno::ENOLINK: ENOLINK (Reserved)>
98 => #<Errno::ENOSR: No STREAM resources>
99 => #<Errno::ENOSTR: Not a STREAM>
100 => #<Errno::EPROTO: Protocol error>
101 => #<Errno::ETIME: STREAM ioctl timeout>
102 => #<Errno::EOPNOTSUPP: Operation not supported on socket>
103 => #<SystemCallError: Policy not found>
104 => #<Errno::ENOTRECOVERABLE: State not recoverable>
105 => #<Errno::EOWNERDEAD: Previous owner died>
106 => #<SystemCallError: Interface output queue is full>
107 => #<SystemCallError: Unknown error: 107>
108 => #<SystemCallError: Unknown error: 108>
109 => #<SystemCallError: Unknown error: 109>
110 => #<SystemCallError: Unknown error: 110>
```